# Windows Universal ToastNotification not displayed, But available in Action Center

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal

I create and post a Toast as follows:

```
public async Task Handle(Alert a) {
  var tst = String.Format(@"<toast><visual><binding template='ToastGeneric'><text>Alert</text><text>{0}</text></binding></visual></toast>", a.Msg);
  var xml = new XmlDocument();
  xml.LoadXml(tst);
  var tn = new ToastNotification(xml);
  var t = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
  tn.Dismissed += (s, e) => {
    t.TrySetResult(true);
    PersistLog.i(TAG, "Handle:Toast Dismissed:" + e.Reason);
  };
  tn.Failed += (s, e) => {
    t.TrySetResult(false);
    PersistLog.i(TAG, "Handle:Toast Failed");
  };
  */
  ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier().Show(tn);
  var how = await t.Task;
}
```

The Toast Never displays. If Does call the Dismissed CB ... and the Reason is UserCancelled. Why ??? It does show up in the Windows 10 (Anniversary) Action Center.
I have tried calling this from a UI thread as well from the App's OnBackgroundActivated event. The latter is where I really want to call this from ... I want to display a Toast when my App is activated as a Background task from an WNS event.

Comment: Could you share a[mcve]? Toast Notification works well in my side.